# Why does Time.zone get set to nil inside Thread

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4

Here what I mean ...

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'activesupport','4.2.6'
require 'active_support/all'

Time.zone = 'EST'
puts "Print the current Time zone -- [#{Time.zone}]"

Thread.new do 
  puts "Time zone(will be nil) instead thread -- [#{Time.zone}]"
end

sleep 1
```

O/P

```
Print the current Time zone -- ((GMT-05:00) EST)
Time zone(will be nil) instead thread -- ()
```

Clearly rails is doing some magic over here for Time.zone inside thread.

So my question are ..

1. Why Rails is doing this magic?
2. Where in Rails code does it do that.(a link to the code would be great)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at [`Time.zone`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb#L10) you can see it is only set for the current thread, so this seems intended behaviour.

You can either store in a variable and call it that way or set Time.zone to 'EST' every time in you create a thread and then call Time.zone subsequently.

Here's an example of what's happening

```
Thread.current[:foo] = 'bar'

Thread.current[:foo]
#=> "bar"

Thread.new { p Thread.current[:foo] }
#=> nil
```

I'm not able to answer why Rails does magic for many of the things it does, but I believe it may be so every thread can operate on a different Time zone.

Comment: That answered my 2nd  question

Answer (score 4):

You need to set default_zone:

```rb
Time.zone_default = Time.find_zone! 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Comment: This fixed it for us using Grape! Thank you!